# Upload and embed video on site

Tags: javascript, file-upload, upload

I'm trying to build a site where users can upload videos, which will be embedded for other users to view and download. I have tried using Vimeo, but I would need Vimeo Pro in order to store others' videos on my account which is too expensive for my organization. How can I do this?

Comment: All you need is some coding for both front and back ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

Convert the videos to JW Player files, upload them to an S3 bucket, and point the bucket to a CloudFront Web distribution. More on this [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/TutorialStreamingJWPlayer.html).

In that tutorial the videos are uploaded manually to an S3 bucket. Because your use case needs the upload to happen programmatically, you need to use an SDK for S3 in your code. Here's [a tutorial on how to do it in PHP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/usingHLmpuPHP.html) (with other languages available in the sidebar).

These services are not free but cheap.

Suppose you upload 100 videos, 1 GB each in one month. This will cost you about $2.85 for S3.

Suppose the users view the total of 100 GB, with an average object size of 1 GB, and 100% of users are in United States. This will cost you about $7.10 for CloudFront.